# How to fire on onclick event on clicking on an anchor text

Tags: javascript

I would like to fire an onclick event using Javascript whenever an user clicks on "Remoe Item". Given below is the actual code available. The problem is I do not see any id, class to identify the click on this anchor text. Any idea how to do that?

```
<a href="javascript:removeCartItem('ci6223000698')">Remove Item</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Roy

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the Click Event using this selector `[href="#"]` and set an attribute `data-value`.

**Run this code snippet:**

```js
var removeCartItem = function(value) {
   console.log(`You're about to remove this item: ${value}`);
};

var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('[href="#"]');
for (a of anchors) {
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    removeCartItem(e.target.getAttribute('data-value'));
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-value='ci6223000698'>Remove Item</a>
<a href="#" data-value='ci6223000677'>Remove Item</a>
```

See? the value was printed from your function `removeCartItem`.

## Bonus with jQuery

Using the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) looks fancier.

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

**Run this code snippet:**

```js
var removeCartItem = function(value) {
   console.log(`You're about to remove this item: ${value}`);
};

$('[href="#"]').click(function() {
  removeCartItem($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-value='ci6223000698'>Remove Item</a>
<a href="#" data-value='ci6223000677'>Remove Item</a>
```

Comment: this is a nice solution...+1 for that

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an `EventHandler`:

```
<a href="#" id="remove" onclick="myFunction('ci6223000698')">Remove Item</a>
```

while you'd need to have a function like this:

```
function myFunction(myVar) { //... }
```

or if you prefer adding the handler js side:

```
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener("click", function() {
  // your stuff
})
```

or with jQuery:

```
$('#remove').click(function() { //.... })
```

example in fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/txy5tyg2/1/

further reading:

[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: You're losing this value `ci6223000698`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all  tag and add an event listener.

you can find the examples here,
[How to add click event to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975708/how-to-add-click-event-to-an-element)