# Insert HTML and Script in Button HTML

Tags: php, html, button, insert

I have this , how i make this working with click on a button

```
<span class="glf-button" data-glf-cuid="XXX" data-glf-ruid="XXXX" > MEN&Uuml; ansehen & bestellen</span>
```

How i make that when i Click the Button that it works?

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add click event to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975708/how-to-add-click-event-to-an-element)

Comment: btw: `& bestellen` should be `&amp; bestellen`